# Delaying Movement of Servo after button press - Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, servo

Recently I have been working on a project where the main goal is to move a servo on a model rocket to deploy a parachute. I want to make is so that 10 seconds after I press the button the parachute is released. I have some code for this already but It is not working, as it stops the code completely. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
#include <Servo.h>

// constants won't change
const int BUTTON_PIN = 7; // Arduino pin connected to button's pin
const int SERVO_PIN  = 9; // Arduino pin connected to servo motor's pin

Servo servo; // create servo object to control a servo

// variables will change:
int angle = 0;          // the current angle of servo motor
int lastButtonState;    // the previous state of button
int currentButtonState; // the current state of button

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);                // initialize serial
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP); // set arduino pin to input pull-up mode
  servo.attach(SERVO_PIN);           // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object

  servo.write(angle);
  currentButtonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);
}

void loop() {
  lastButtonState    = currentButtonState;      // save the last state
  currentButtonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN); // read new state

  if(lastButtonState == HIGH && currentButtonState == LOW) {
    Serial.println("The button is pressed");
    time.delay(10000)
    
    // change angle of servo motor
    if(angle == 0)
      angle = 90;
    else
    if(angle == 90)
      angle = 0;

    // control servo motor arccoding to the angle
    servo.write(angle);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Arduino, a delay is usually done with `delay(10000);` (for 10 seconds). I've never seen or heard of the `time.delay()` function, so that might be the issue. Otherwise the code looks like it should work as you want.

It also might depend on the board you're running it on. I remember having issues using `delay()` for long periods on an ESP8266 although I'm pretty sure that it is fine for tens of seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using a Arduino Micro . My idea is to press the button on the ground and then launch it so that the parachute delays a few seconds after apogee.  I actually need about a minute delay for this to work so I can get away quick enough.